# Python Http Server: shut down server when shared queue has N items

Tags: python, http, simplehttpserver

I'm implementing an HTTP server using python `BaseHttpServer`.

I have a `queue` that is shared by different threads. And each time my handler receives a request, it puts it into the shared `queue`. When the number of requests in `queue` reaches `n`, I'd like to shutdown the server. Here's what I have right now:

```
while self.queue.qsize() != n
     self.server.handle_request()
```

My concern about this approach is that, it is possible that when checking `self.queue.qsize()` it's not yet n, but after that the size becomes n immediately (because the `queue` is shared by multiple threads) and there's no following requests anymore. Given that `server.handle_request()` blocks if there is no requests, the server may shutdown anymore. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Bind a thread to the process:

```
httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('', 80), MyHandler)
print("Starting server in thread")
threading.Thread(target=httpd.serve_forever).start()
```

Shutting Down:

```
toKill = threading.Event()

# in handler
toKill.set()

# in main thread
toKill.wait()
httpd.shutdown()
```